# SourceDataLine skipping a specified number of bytes(JavaSound)

Tags: java, audio, javasound

For some reasons, I need to use `SourceDataLine` instead of `Clip` to playback audios in my program. It is easy to assign the `framePosition` (that I want to skip) to `Clip`, but `SourceDataLine` doesn't have this convenient API.

I want to use `AudioInputStream.skip(n)`, where `n` is the requested number of bytes to be skipped. But I don't know how to set `n` properly, if I want to skip 1.25 seconds. How can I do this?

My code is from this [site(MP3 player sample)](https://odoepner.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/play-mp3-or-ogg-using-javax-sound-sampled-mp3spi-vorbisspi/).
Please check the `in.skip()` in function `stream`

```
public class AudioFilePlayer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final AudioFilePlayer player = new AudioFilePlayer ();
    player.play("something.mp3");
}

public void play(String filePath) {
    final File file = new File(filePath);

    try (final AudioInputStream in = getAudioInputStream(file)) {

        final AudioFormat outFormat = getOutFormat(in.getFormat());
        final Info info = new Info(SourceDataLine.class, outFormat);

        try (final SourceDataLine line =
                 (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info)) {

            if (line != null) {
                line.open(outFormat);
                line.start();
                stream(getAudioInputStream(outFormat, in), line);
                line.drain();
                line.stop();
            }
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException 
           | LineUnavailableException 
           | IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}

private AudioFormat getOutFormat(AudioFormat inFormat) {
    final int ch = inFormat.getChannels();
    final float rate = inFormat.getSampleRate();
    return new AudioFormat(PCM_SIGNED, rate, 16, ch, ch * 2, rate, false);
}

private void stream(AudioInputStream in, SourceDataLine line) 
    throws IOException {
    in.skip(proper number); //There is my question
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
    for (int n = 0; n != -1; n = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) {
        line.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
}}
```

Comment: *"For some reasons.."* What reasons? See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Original file is MP3, which `Clip` could not open.

Comment: That's odd.. A `Clip` and the `AudioInputStream` can open the exact same audio types. MP3 is supported for both if the codec is placed on the run-time class-path. The only problem I had with opening MP3s using a `Clip` was that the maximum size of a `Clip` was very small. I wrote `BigClip` to get around those problems. Maybe it would solve this..

Comment: @AndrewThompson , when I trying to open it with `Clip`, I got this error `line with format MPEG1L3 44100.0 Hz, unknown bits per sample, stereo, unknown frame size, 38.28125 frames/second, not supported.`.

Comment: And `SourceDataLine` just plays the file fine, I only need to figure out how to skip specified bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Each `AudioInputStream` has an `AudioFormat` object, which you can get via the [format()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html#format) method. To find out how many bytes are `1.25` seconds, you need to calculate how many frames `1.25` seconds are and how big a frame is:

```
AudioFormat format = audioInputStream.format();
float b = format.getFrameSize() * format.getFrameRate() * 1.25f;
// round to nearest full frame
long n = (b/format.getFrameSize())*format.getFrameSize();
long skipped = audioInputStream.skip(b);
// you might want to check skipped to see whether the
// requested number of bytes was indeed skipped.
```

To explain:

- A *Frame* is one full sample for all channels. So if you have a stereo signal, a frame is two samples, left and right.
- *FrameSize* is the number of bytes used for a frame. For CD quality this would be 2 bytes per channel, i.e. 4 bytes per frame (in case of stereo).
- *FrameRate* is the number of frames per second.
- Since you should not split frames you have to round to whole frames.

Note that the code above assumes you have PCM encoded audio. If you have something else, first transcode to PCM using something like `pcmStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, audioInputStream)`.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it,`frameSize(4)*framerate(44100)*1.25`. But it skips too many bytes, my audio is 3-sec long, and it skips it all.

Comment: I added details to my post, please check it out.

Comment: This may be mp3spi's fault. Just to test, convert your mp3 file to wave and try with that.

Comment: Also, check what `in.skip(proper number);` returns.

Comment: Yes, it works perfect on wave, do I have any chances to fix the problem on MP3 file?

Comment: Which OS are you on? Do you need a pure Java solution?

Comment: Both Win and Mac OS, I hope it's a pure Java solution.

Comment: You could try another mp3 service provider, like [FFSampledSP](http://www.tagtraum.com/ffsampledsp/). It's not pure Java, but the native part is available for both macOS and Windows. Just make sure you put the right lib in your library path. Disclosure: I'm the author.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out.

Comment: FFSampledSP needs ffmpeg binary, it's over 20Mb, much bigger than my main program. Also it might be a problem if I want to include it in my application.

Comment: Actually, the macOS dylib is 11Mb (on macOS just the dylib is required), but I see your point. I should probably make an effort to strip down the FFmpeg part.

Comment: Back to your problem: Why don't you just try `read(new byte[n])` instead of `skip(n)`? Perhaps that's implemented properly in mp3spi.

Comment: Did you mean change the starting index of `n` in the for-loop(stream fun)?

Comment: No. Simply replace `in.skip(n)` with in.read(new byte[n]). It should have the same effect (just discard what you read). In either case, you *must* check the return value to make sure you *actually* skipped/read the requested number of bytes.

Comment: I checked the return value for both(MP3), `in.skip(n)` returns a number very close to `n` (a bit lesser), `read(new byte[n])` returns a number quite less than `n`. They both return the same number as `n` when I test it with wave.

Comment: Well, if the returned number is less than what you wanted, read again until you have read enough!

Comment: No... but you progress further in the stream. Please read up on basic stream handling in Java.